# Unable to open Chrome as normal user but works as root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome

I installed Google Chrome via terminal in an Ubuntu based AWS instance by following: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-linux-12-xx-13-xx/

Problem is that I can invoke Chrome as root user but not as normal user:
[image]

This is my installation directory:
[image]

I manipulated access permissions using chmod trying to debug the issue but, had no luck solving it.

How can I invoke Chrome as normal user in this case?

Because of this issue, when I run tests via Jenkins I am getting this error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome

Comment: Firstly, do not follow unofficial guides to install stuff

Comment: You could have done `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/985712) answer

Comment: I followed the instructions at (https://askubuntu.com/questions/67047/how-to-uninstall-google-chrome/67050) to remove chrome fully. Then I installed it following the steps in the link you gave. Installation was successful. But this is what I see now:

qa_user@jenkins-it02:/usr/bin$ whereis google-chrome
google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1.gz
qa_user@jenkins-it02:/usr/bin$ google-chrome
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

google-chrome: command not found

Comment: Hmm.. [Chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215460/room-for-d4rk4ng31-and-afsal)?

Comment: Sure, how do I join?

Comment: Do not post images of text!

Comment: When this question was posted (which I assume was not many years after the problem was encountered, any guide addressing ubuntu 12/13 was way out of date. It should have come as no surprise that following it would have caused problems.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the actual fix for this issue but I could get around my actual blocker by installing Chromium instead of Chrome.
Difference I found is the installation directory of both.

I installed Chrome using the link shared by @d4rk4ng31.
whereis Google-Chrome-Stable gives:

qa_user@jenkins:~$ whereis google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome-stable.1.gz

And qa_user@jenkins:~$ google-chrome-stable gives:
google-chrome-stable: command not found

Now for Chromium:

qa_user@jenkins:~$ whereis chromium-browser gives:
chromium-browser: /usr/bin/chromium-browser /usr/lib/chromium-browser /etc/chromium-browser /usr/share/chromium-browser /usr/share/man/man1/chromium-browser.1.gz

and 
qa_user@jenkins~$ chromium-browser
[21304:21304:0607/135202.629230:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1473)] Unable to open X display.
Identifies and opens Chromium (X display issue can be solved by adding --headless option in actual Selenium code).

So I am gonna use Chromium instead of Chrome until I can fix the actual chrome issue here.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
After the above solution, I uninstalled Chromium and kept only Chrome for further testing. Surprisingly, chrome issue got fixed. I am able to run tests in Chrome now. Not sure how this is happening but I think it has something to do with dependency package that comes with Chrome.